# Invalid use of group function while updating a table with sum function

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two tables: `o_daily_lcsgeneration` and `o_daily_generation`.

While trying to update the `o_daily_generation` I receive an error saying:

```
error(1111) invalid use of Group function
```

Here is the code I am running:

```
update o_daily_generation join o_daily_lcsgeneration 
on o_daily_generation.Location =o_daily_lcsgeneration.Location 
   and o_daily_generation.Date =o_daily_lcsgeneration.Date  
set o_daily_lcsgeneration.Turbine_Generation =sum(o_daily_generation.Turbine_Generation)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
UPDATE o_daily_generation od
INNER JOIN 
(
     SELECT Location, SUM(Turbine_Generation) TurbineSum
     FROM o_daily_lcsgeneration
     GROUP BY Location
) og ON od.Location = og.Location
SET od.Turbine_Generation = og.TurbineSum
```

Comment: ^ missing table alias

Answer (score 2):

I did update the above query based on above answer but there is an issue.

```
UPDATE tmpTotal t1
    INNER JOIN 
    (
         SELECT thirdlevel_delivery_id, MAX(baseline_id) MaxBaseLineId
         FROM tmpTotal
         GROUP BY release_id
    ) t2 ON t1.release_id = t2.release_id
    SET t1.planned_delivery_date = t2.MaxBaseLineId;
```

It gives

```
Error Code : 1054
Unknown column 't2.release_id' in 'on clause'
```

Comment: You have to select the column `release_id` in the statment called `t2` in order to use it in the join clause.