# How can I use group functions on a spatial JOIN to update a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, left-join, case, spatial-query

I'm trying to update the total revenue for offices located in different geographies. The geographies are defined by circles and polygons which are both in the shapes.shape column.

When I run the query below, MySQL throws "R_INVALID_GROUP_FUNC_USE: Invalid use of group function"

I tried to adapt [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207069/invalid-use-of-group-function-while-updating-a-table-with-sum-function/19933729) answer, but I can't figure out the logic with the conditional join and geospatial data -- it's not as simple as adding a subquery with a WHERE clause. (Or is it?)

For context, I have about 350 geographies and 150,000 offices.

```
UPDATE
    shapes s
    LEFT JOIN offices ON (
        CASE
            WHEN s.type = 'circle' THEN ST_Distance_Sphere(o.coords, s.shape) < s.radius
            ELSE ST_CONTAINS(s.shape, o.coords)
        END
    )
SET
    s.totalRevenue = SUM(o.revenue);
```

UPDATE:

This works, but it's slow and confusing. Is there a faster/more concise way?

```
UPDATE
    shapes s
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            t.shape_id,
            SUM(g.revenue) revenue
        FROM
            shapes t
            LEFT JOIN offices o ON (
                CASE
                    WHEN t.type = 'circle' THEN ST_Distance_Sphere(o.coords, t.shape) < t.radius
                    ELSE ST_CONTAINS(t.shape, o.coords)
                END
            )
        GROUP BY
            t.shape_id
    ) b ON s.shape_id = b.shape_id
SET
    s.totalRevenue = b.revenue;
```

Comment: if you supply sql fiddle we can help optimize it

Comment: Provide table description, some datas and expected result.

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Please fix the  queries -- the alias `o` is not defined in the first query and `g` is not defined in the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think that speed can be helped by splitting into two `UPDATEs`:

```
... WHERE t.type = 'circle' 
      AND ST_Distance_Sphere ...
```

and

```
... WHERE t.type != 'circle' 
      AND ST_CONCAINS ...
```

And then see if the resulting SQLs can be simplified.

To further investigate the query, please isolate the subquery `b` and see if the bulk of the time is in doing that `SELECT` (as opposed to the time doing the `UPDATE`).

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table and `EXPLAIN` for both the `UPDATE(s)` and the isolated `SELECT(s)`.  A number of clues might come from such.